# linear ODE change of variable in general form solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving linear ODE of form:
$$ y' + p(t)y = g(t) $$

we are looking for an integrating factor u(t), which is given by a formula:

$$ u(t) = \int p(t)dt $$

Now a solution to this form of ODE is:

$$ y(t) =  \frac {1}{u(t)} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} p(v)dv +\frac {c}{u(t)} $$

Now in the textbook I use it says that we switch the variable inside the integral from t to v to show that t is an independent variable, so we choose some convenient integration limits and swap them. I understand how to change variable inside integral, but my question is why? Why do we need to change t to v and how does it help us show that t is independent?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is done in order to distinguish "*dummy*" integrating variable from a "*real*" independent variable of which solution depends.

Also, note that they say *"switch variables"*, i.e. simply reliable them. This has nothing to do with *"substitutional change of variables"*, which is replacing a free variable appearing in an equation by an expression depending on other variables.